# Read a specific block of rows from a sparse matrix in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, matrix, mapreduce

I have a matrix store as follows

> rowid, columnid, value

I want to read only a chunk of rows and send it to a mapper. For example, rows with id= 1,2,3,4  to a mapper, 5,6,7,8 to another one, ...
Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is probably not possible unless you jump through some serious hoops. This is what the reduce phase is for! Make the rowid your reduce key (or some calculation based on it... like `(rowid-1)/4`) and those chunks will be sent to the same reducer.

Comment: From your suggestion, I have an idea that each reducer writes to a folder. Then, for the next step, I can specify the mapper in the next to read from the specific folder. What do you think ?

Comment: Why do you need them to be separated by row chunks in the mapper specifically? My suggestion was to do in the reducer whatever you had planned to do in the mapper. If you have additional processing to do after that, you an do it in another mapreduce phase, like you suggested.